# Error using azure-eventhubs python example

Tags: python, azure

I'm attempting to use the example code to receive data from Azure Event Hub.

Heres the code

```py
import os
import sys
import logging
import time
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset

logger = logging.getLogger("azure")

ADDRESS = "amqps://mine.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=sadfsafdljksad=<eventhub>"
```

But I am getting the following error when executing..

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./recv.py", line 5, in <module>
    from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset
ImportError: cannot import name 'EventHubClient'
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Please note this is just a snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually installed [azure-eventhub package, version 5.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/). But `EventHubClient` does not exist in 5.0.0 version, it exists in [azure-eventhub package, version 1.3.3](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/1.3.3/) or below.

By default, when you install the azure eventhub package for python using this command `pip install azure-eventhub`, it will automatically install the latest version 5.0.0. So this sentence `from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset` will throw the error **ImportError: cannot import name 'EventHubClient'**

You can check the version of the package by open cmd -> input command `pip show azure-eventhub`. Screenshot as below:

[image]

There are 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:** keep using the 5.0.0 version, then you should re-write your code and follow the examples in this [doc](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/).

**Solution 2:** If you want to use the current code which includes `from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset`, you should first uninstall the `5.0.0 version` of azure-eventhub, then reinstall the `1.3.3 version` by using this command `pip install azure-eventhub==1.3.3`

Comment: Both using the 1.3.3 code and 5.0.0 code they work (with the appropriate version installed).  But now I'm getting authentication errors.  So, using the example for 5.0.0 (Thanks for the link Ivan), if I'm logged in to the azure portal, under Event hubs and then select my event hub, where do I find these values:

connection_str = '<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>'
consumer_group = '<< CONSUMER GROUP >>'
eventhub_name = '<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>'

Comment: @TNTimmy, as per your comment, I'm not sure if you're using the correct connection string. You should use `Event Hub Namespace level connection string`, follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string#get-connection-string-from-the-portal). You **cannot** use `Event Hub instance level connection string`.

Comment: @TNTimmy, have you solved your issue? if the answer works for you, could you please help accept it as answer by following this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks:).

Answer (score 0):

Using this solution works fine 
reinstall the 1.3.3 version by using this command pip install azure-eventhub==1.3.3